# Firebase Cloud Functions onWrite get all new entries

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This `events` function works when data is added for the first time, but when adding additional entries, `change.after.val()` returns all entries, not just the new ones.

Can I somehow get all new entries or do I have to do `fcm/{pushId}/{uid}`, get each individual user id and send that to  `sendNotification`?

```
exports.events = functions.database.ref('/fcm/{pushId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

        // Exit when the data is deleted.
        if (!change.after.exists()) {
            return null;
        }

        const eventId = context.params.pushId;
        const dsnap = change.after.val();

        let guests = Object.keys(dsnap);

        const promises = guests.map((data) => admin.database()
            .ref('playerIds')
            .child(data)
            .once('value'));

        return Promise.all(promises).then(data => {

            return data.map(item => {
                let itemVal = Object.keys(item.val());
                return itemVal;
            })
        }).then((itemVal) => {

            if (itemVal) {
                console.log('itemVal', itemVal)
                admin.database().ref(`/events/${eventId}/`)
                    .once('value')
                    .then(event => {
                        if (event) {


                            let playerIds = [];

                            for (let id of itemVal) {
                                playerIds.push(id[0]);
                            }

                            let msg = "Your invitation has arrived!";

                            var eventObject = { "eventKey": eventId, "event": event };
                            sendNotification(playerIds, msg, eventObject);
                        }
                    })
            }

        });

    });
```

Database model:

```
fcm
  Eventid1
      UID1: true,
      UID2: true
  Event2
      UID2: true,
      ...
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you gave some illustration and/or description of what your database looks like, so we don't have to guess by reverse engineering the code.  Maybe also a more detailed description of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi. I updated my question. I use the user's his to get the playerid which in turn is used to send a notification.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you're trying to do, and the database model doesn't seem to match the code.

Comment: Sorry. Updated the model. So when a user is invited to an event, I save the event's I'd in fcm and in it I add all the guest IDs. But thinking about it I might change things around a bit. My approach is too complicated.

Comment: Instead of creating an array with playerIds you should create an array with tokens and send all notifications at once